# Javascript regex for first 3 words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having issues trying to isolate and remove the first 3 words from a string.

The string is: "LES B1 U01 1.1 Discussing what kind of job you want"

I need to make it: "1.1 Discussing what kind of job you want"

I was able to get the first word using 
/^([\w-]+)/

Any help would be appreciated!

PS. I'm using jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the correct track. I have created a regexp type fiddle [here](http://regexr.com/39h42) to show you have it works.

```
/^([\S]+)\s([\S]+)\s([\S]+)/g
```

Essentially what this does is look for any non-space character 1 or more times followed by a whitespace character then non-space 1 or more times, whitespace, then the last set of non-space characters giving you your three words.

Answer (score 6):

To remove first three words, separated by space you can use String's `split` and Array's `slice` and `join`.

```
"LES B1 U01 1.1 Discussing what kind ...".split(' ').slice(3).join(' ');
```

Comment: using slice was better than my approach, +1 although I am not unaware of slice, my answer was provided by my thoughts as my initial.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sentence = "LES B1 U01 1.1 Discussing what kind of job you want";
var words = sentence.split(/\s/);

words.shift(); // shift removes the first element in the array
words.shift(); // ..
words.shift(); // ..

alert(words.join(" "));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7fLytvg/

This is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "LES B1 U01 1.1 Discussing what kind of job you want";
console.log( str.replace(/^(?:\w+\s+){3}/,'') );
```

Will output `1.1 Discussing what kind of job you want`